# Share class between widget and activity in android

Tags: android, android-activity, initialization, widget

I'll try to explain my idea:
I have 1 widget with all his things(xml layout,widget provider...)
Widget consists in one ImageView that updates every 24h. 
Also if user press on widget, it launch an activity. 
I want to have one class Counter.java that could be accessed from widget and from activity at same time. 
But I don't want to initialize that class each time I access on it. Just once to create. I dont' know when do it and where.

One more question:

How to detect the moment when Activity is started from widget. And when it comes back to widget?

Comment: You *have to* initialize objects where you need it, once for one activity, once for one widget, once for one service, etc.

Comment: but this means that each time I press widget, it launch Activity, and Activity initialize the object that already has been initialized in widget. I want to pass only one int value... But if I initialize the object Counter in widget. When im in Activity, how to access that obeject? I have to initialize it or somehow get it? Help

Comment: You should save your data on storage, such as `SharedPreferences` and just grab the values from there and use it globally. No need for multiple object instances.

Comment: solved with sharedPreferences